# How to remove hash from Url in meanjs app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meanjs

I need to remove '#' from the urls. It can be done by setting

> $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});

But when i do so, my routes are going to Nodejs routes.
Ex: 
http://example.com/#/login  -- it will open login page but after removing hashbangs its hitting nodejs routes - http://example.com/login.

The application is completed, So i can't change the implementation now.

Please help.

EDIT:
These are the few stateProvider

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'partials/landing.html',
        controller: 'mainController',
        controllerAs: 'main',
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'mainCtrl',
                    files: [
                        'plugins/raty/jquery.raty.js',
                        'js/controllers/HomeController.js'
                    ]
                });
            }]
        }
    })


    .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'landingController',
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'mainCtrl',
                        files: [
                            'js/controllers/HomeController.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })
```

Comment: Can you paste the routeprovider here?

Comment: @Nitheesh : i added.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your config block

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

In your index.html file set base by adding below line in head tag of html page

```
<base href="/" >
```

and then in node server.js handle your routes by adding below code

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("index.html",{root:__dirname+'/public'}); 
   //load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```

Comment: are you still getting # in the urls?

Comment: No, that is getting removed but my angular route is not working its going in node route.